# How to fix production build with amplify-authenticator in Angular 9 project?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I've got a project using Angular 9 that has an `<amplify-authenticator>` element, and have imported `AmplifyUIAngularModule` from `@aws-amplify/ui-angular` in the single module in the project. It runs fine in a dev build, but when I try to do a production build, it fails:

```
ERROR in src/app/signin/signin.page.html:13:5 - error NG8001: 'amplify-authenticator' is not a known element:
1. If 'amplify-authenticator' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'amplify-authenticator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

13     <amplify-authenticator [handleAuthStateChange]="handleAuthStateChange">
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/signin/signin.page.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: 'signin.page.html',
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SigninPage.
```

I'm using the new [Amplify UI Components for Angular](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/angular), so as far as I can tell there's nothing else to import. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please import `AmplifyUIAngularModule` in the same `NgModule` that `SignPageComponent` is declared in.

AOT (Ahead of Time) compiler resolve the NgModules in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I had forgotten to put `SigninPage` itself into the module. Adding it to `declarations` fixed the problem. No idea how the app was able to run with the JIT compiler...‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I was building my release as follows:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Only after removing the `--prod` parameter, I assume the profile, did it start working.